# Shooting an invisible rabbit

Tags: calculation-puzzle, strategy

An invisible rabbit sits on one of the posts of an infinite fence. A local farmer cannot stand this fact and wants to shoot the rabbit down*. Every time the farmer shoots her gun, the rabbit jumps to another post along the fence (not quickly enough to avoid the shot, though). The jump is always in the same direction and the same distance.

How can the farmer make sure she hits the rabbit with a finite number of shots?

* Not to kill it, of course, just to get it off the fence. It's a water gun.

Comment: And once I've knocked off the rabbit I can hear him hit the ground, yes?

Comment: @BenFrankel Yes.

Comment: Looks very similar to [the recent submarine question](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11653/sink-the-submarine)...

Comment: @randal'thor I marked it as duplicate. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: It should be noted that the duplicate question does not solve this in a finite number of shots. The only claim is that it can be done in a countable number of shots. The integers are countable and infinite, so these obviously do not equate.

Comment: Additionally, the so-called duplicate question moves the submarine at a constant rate relative to time. This is in no way related to the number of shots fired. This question moves the rabbit each time the gun is fired.

Comment: @IanMacDonald, Actually the duplicate question does indeed require only a finite number of shots, and the nuance that the submarine will still move even if we do not shoot does indeed change the question; however, the solution provided there does shoot every hour and is thus also relevant to this question.

Comment: @BenFrankel, the duplicate question most certainly does not require a finite number of shots. The wording specifically says "unlimited number" and "eventually sink". Nowhere does it stipulate that this must be done with a finite number of shots.

Comment: @IanMacDonald, Oh. I meant that the answer solves the question in finite time and it shoots every hour, so it works for this question too. The questions are different, but only on a very shallow level.

Comment: @BenFrankel, you have also misinterpreted the accepted answer on that question. It notes that there are an infinite number of combinations of $A$ and $B$, but notes that the submarine will eventually be sunk. "Eventually" here does not imply finite, but is instead more indicative of the convergence of a limit.

Comment: @IanMacDonald, Yes, he *says* eventually. His method works in finite time however. $A$ and $B$ are finite, thus $f(A,B)$ is finite, where $f$ is the function defined by the imaged spiral. He hits the submarine $(A,B)$ after $f(A,B)$ hours. EDIT: I'm talking about the accepted solution, ie, Allan's solution.

Comment: @BenFrankel, no, his algorithm loops through ***all*** combinations of $A$ and $B$ at any given time $t$. An individual function result for an individual $(A,B)$ pair may be finite, but the number of combinations that are iterated in his algorithm at every time $t$ is ***not*** finite.

Comment: I don't think this is possible with a finite number of shots. The rabbit can start anywhere on the infinite fence. Am I missing something?

Comment: @IanMacDonald, I don't quite understand what you're saying. He only shoots once every hour, yes? Each time his shot checks if the submarine is $(X,Y)$. Either he hits and he wins, or he fails and he checks the "next" $(X,Y)$ on the next hour. Thus in finite time he reaches the constant $(A,B)$ of the submarine.

Comment: If that's what he's saying, it certainly won't catch the submarine. Consider a submarine travelling along the path $x=y$. If you miss on the first shot, the submarine gets progressively further and further away from your spiral. For example, his 31st shot is at $(4,4)$ when the submarine would be already at $(32,32)$ and getting further away. This does not converge if you only fire one shot, hence this cannot possibly be what he meant.

Comment: @Ian It sounds like you misinterpreted the solution to the linked puzzle. The spaces in the spiral do not represent locations in space. They represent possible starting states of the sub, which the spiral eliminates one by one. For any starting state, the solution sinks the sub in finite time. However, without knowing the sub's position, there is no finite bound on how long the process might take; nor, trivially, is such a uniform bound possible for any solution.

Comment: @Lopsy, then you're in agreement that there is no finite termination to the process.

Comment: @IanMacDonald There will always be a finite termination to the process. If you are so intent that it's possible there won't be, give an example of values for A and B for which the process won't terminate.

Comment: @Taylor: His solution just isn't worded very well, I suppose, with the graph being unnecessary (and misleading at a glance).

Comment: It actually is a finite problem. You can think of the solution as a single point on the A-B plane. You will *always* hit the solution (using the spiral) no matter what.

Comment: I'm not sure how the graph could've been misleading. The question is talking about a submarine on a *number line*; that is a one-dimensional number line. Perhaps you misinterpreted the question.

Comment: Does the rabbit have to move a fixed displacement each time? If not, it seems impossible to win in finite steps with certainty. It could be that each time you shoot, it was one space to the right of whereever you shot.

Comment: @xnor Yes, the jump is always in the same direction and the same distance. Still, the situation you describe is possible, and therefore shooting at post $N+C$, where $N$ is the shot number and $C$ is some constant, is not a good strategy.